# Firefox for Android refuses loading any website

Tags: firefox-for-android, android-12, https

I wanted to give Firefox for Android a try (I'm a long-time Chrome user), but after installing it from the Play Store, I discovered it refuses to load any website, always showing this security warning that cannot be ignored:

[image: This website requires a secure connection]

This happens on all sites and only on Firefox for Android, the same sites load correctly in Chrome and also load correctly in Firefox running on a Windows computer that is on the same network as my Android device.

Any clues as to why this is happening? I'm running Firefox 105.1.0 on Android 12.

Comment: Check the system date. If it is wrong HTTPS connections will fail because the used certificate is not yet or no longer valid.

Comment: AFAIK, Firefox uses its own certificate store, not the Android native certificate store. What happens if you try [setting `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` to `true` on `about:config`](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1304237)?

Comment: @Robert: thanks but date was ok, problem was a different one, check my answer for details

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks for the comment, it pointed me in the right direction to solve the issue, see my answer for details

Comment: @Master_T So your device is rooted (-> not mentioned in question)? because otherwise you could not have installed a root CA certificate.

Comment: @Robert reading the [AdGuard's official documentation](https://kb.adguard.com/en/android/overview#https-filtering-1), looks like root is not needed.

Comment: @AndrewT. That description can only work for Chrome. For apps this can not work as they don't accept user installed certificates. May be AdGuard only applies HTTPS interception to Chrome and other white-listed apps.

Comment: @Robert: no it's not rooted, you can manually install a ca certificate on any modern operating system, android included. Also, apps can use them just fine, it's just that in Firefox they're excluded by default, but if you check the link in my answer you will see how to enable if via the advanced options menu

Comment: @Master_T Yes you can install certificates but Google has changed the behavior starting with Android 6. All apps that target this version or newer have to explicitly opt-in user certs in their config. Otherwise such certificates are treated by the standard Android functions as untrusted (like the cert is not installed).

Comment: @Robert: indeed I needed to opt in with Firefox. What I don't know is why it's a hidden setting in the debug menu, but whatever, it works and that's the important thing

Comment: Have you tried Pale Moon Web Browser, it's based on Firefox source code but is not affiliated with Mozilla, that is my limited understanding of it.  The only time I've seen that sort of error your getting is for using an outdated version of a browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing more digging, it seems the problem was my adblocker (AdGuard). It uses a locally installed CA certificate in order to filter HTTPS traffic. By default Firefox ignores local CA certificates, it has its own list of trusted CAs. Quite dumb in my opinion, but luckily local CA certificates can be enabled by following this guide:

https://kb.adguard.com/en/android/solving-problems/firefox-certificates

Comment: Instead of using a VPN app you can avoid issues like this by setting your private DNS to their server. https://adguard-dns.io/en/public-dns.html

Comment: @Tanath: that is not nearly as effective though, a lot more ads get through if you only use DNS filtering...

Comment: It's DNS filtering either way, and my experience has barely any ads getting through. It's even the same provider so the filters should be the same.